# CSS Column Layouts

Tags: html, css

I'm new at web design and I’m doing a 2 column layout web site. After reading a couple tutorials, one of them said the best approach is using 'the box model' concept which means (+-) not positioning every single element.

What’s the best approach? The easy one?

Can someone supply an example layout?

Comment: Hi, If you stick up come CSS you've written then the clever SO elves will be more inclined to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to web design I strongly recommend reading [this](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/07/7-questions-asked-by-noob-designers-answered/)!

You can only began start making layouts after dominate ‘box model’. 
[Box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) is much more positioning elements, box model says every single element is your page comports like a square that have width, border and margin attributes.

With this attributes you can position an element, eg using margin-left: 100px moves your element 100px from left element!

[My layout](http://jsfiddle.net/rm596/9d9Cu/) is a fluid layout that means I not using ‘fixed’ values such as ‘px’

```
header {
    background: rgb(76, 67, 65);
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    height: 96px;
    padding: 32px 0 0 2%;
}

.col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 2%;
 }
.col2 {
    float: right;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 1.6;
    width: 34%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
footer {
    background: rgb(100, 98, 102);
    height: 80px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Hope this can help!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how new you are exactly at CSS but there are some easy things that you can do. CSS is very flexible. Here are a couple options:

**Option 1:**

If you're going to have more than just text and such in your two columns, you're going to want to probably have two separate containers for the content, in which case you're going to want two `<div>`'s (these are elements that are already set to display as blocks--it makes more sense than other elements).

If you give the divs some css like this:

```
.column {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
```

What this means is the two elements will respect the positions of each other in a line, and each take up exactly half of the line's space.

Another similar option is to give them `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;`. What this means is the elements will "float" above the other elements on the page, pretending as though they don't exist. This means the parent elements won't wrap all the way around them anymore (although this can be prevented with `clear:both;` on an element that comes after them). Float elements are really handy a lot of the time, but I find that inline-block is usually a cleaner option.

**Option 2:**

This is the easy way to do it! If you just have text, you can get away with only using a single element and giving it the css:

```
.columnLayout {
    -webkit-column-count:3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
    column-count:3;
}
```

Have a look at Mozilla Developer Network's [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) on it if you're interested!

It's important to remember that this IS CSS and there are a LOT of options with CSS. I'd recommend to keep trying new things! You never know which will work the best for your designs.

Also, about the box-model thing, a box-model is the "box" that an element displays as. It's important not to define what each box is exactly--or else you'll be teaching yourself the ancient form of how the internet was displayed. There's no fluidity in making a layout that can only work in one resolution, and will only work with certain content!

If you have any questions let me know! =)

Comment: Thanks for giving me this info.